# Why would std::initializer_list copy items?

Tags: c++

I always thought `std::initializer_list` is a lightweight proxy object which would only take const references from list items, instead of copy them.
But then I discovered that copy is actually performed in this case:

```
struct Test {
    Test() { 
        std::cout << this << " default ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test&) {
        std::cout << this << " copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << this << " destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test a;
    Test b;
    Test c;
    std::cout << "for begin" << std::endl;
    for(const auto& current : {a, b, c}) {
        std::cout << "Current: " << &current << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "for end" << std::endl;
}
```

Output of above code:

```
0x63e5acda default ctor
0x63e5acdb default ctor
0x63e5acdc default ctor
for begin
0x63e5acdd copy ctor
0x63e5acde copy ctor
0x63e5acdf copy ctor
Current: 0x63e5acdd
Current: 0x63e5acde
Current: 0x63e5acdf
0x63e5acdf destructor
0x63e5acde destructor
0x63e5acdd destructor
for end
0x63e5acdc destructor
0x63e5acdb destructor
0x63e5acda destructor
```

Why would std::initializer_list copy items in this case, instead of just taking their references? Is there any "elegant" way to write things similar to `for(auto&& x : {a, b, c})`, but without copying existing items?

Comment: I am curious how to make this happen as well. OP can you update your question to ask for a solution as well?

Comment: @texasbruce `{&a, &b, &c}` would avoid the copy

Comment: @M.M That is still copy, of the pointer value. Apparently initializer_list always instantiates a new instance

Comment: @texasbruce copying a pointer value is no problem,  it will probably generate the same code as if iterating over a "list" of references

Comment: @texasbruce from the answer below, `std::initializer_list` has an underlying array, so it looks like `{&a, &b, &c}` would be the only viable solution... or alternatively something like `some_custom_reference_holding_struct{a, b, c}` might work as well, but they might be too lengthy or too ugly to use :/

Comment: @LanYi You can actually use `std::ref` like `{ref(a), ref(b), ref(c)}` It returns a reference_wrapper. But for the best performance, a pointer is probably the best. I think this is worth mentioning to the committee and see if it can have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation on [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which **each element is copy-initialized** (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory.

Comment: Ouch, didn't notice that `std::initializer_list` has an underlying array... it looks like I can only do `{&a, &b, &c}` to avoid copy...